# SSL FATAL ERROR - Handshake Failure (40)

Tags: java, firefox, ssl

I am trying to access the web application hosted in our radius server and the Firefox browser throws this error code `ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap`. The following is the message displayed in the browser.

> An error occurred during a connection to X.X.X.X. Cannot communicate
>   securely with peer: no common encryption algorithm(s). (Error code:
>   ssl_error_no_cypher_overlap)

After surfing the internet, I thought the cipher suites which are exchanged between the client and server caused the problem and tried capturing the packet. Surprisingly there is a common cipher between the client and server and the Server Hello is sent from the server as well.

> Client Hello Packet:

[image]

> Server Hello Packet:

[image]

With in a few seconds, the server sends a fatal error says handshake failure (40).

[image]

Does anyone has faced this issue before and any idea what would have caused the problem?

My server is Java 6 based, it uses the encryption algorithm DSA with SHA1 and I am using the latest Firefox 40.0.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After surfing the internet for a long time, I came to know that the support for DSA encryption is disabled permanently by the latest browsers which caused the handshake failure (40).

There are several security enhancements done in Firefox in the recent days. Read more:

> https://hacks.mozilla.org/2015/04/trainspotting-firefox-37-developer-edition-and-more/

The interesting thing that I am wondering here is, the cipher suites are exchanged between client and server successfully and after few seconds handshake failure is sent from server though there is no packet is exchanged from client.

Anyway, the handshake is happening properly with RSA encryption and I will mark my answer as correct till I get a best answer from someone.

Comment: i have the same problem

Answer (score 0):

I met the same issue, describe the scenario as following:

```
SSL client only support TLSv1.0 with MD5/base SHA, while SSL server support TLSv1-TLSv1.2,
```

It looks goods, while the problem is server only select support `SHA256ANDHIGHER`, while the client does not support `SHA256ANDHIGHER`
Which log prints

```
ACE_SSL (4694|4055886656) error code: 336151568 - error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

It confused me a lot before make it clear, after tcpdump from client side, Alert 21 and Handshke Failure (40) states all:

[image]

Then I change the server to support SHA and MD5(lower version), it succeed !

Just for your reference

Thanks,
Charley